# Finitely Presented Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let the descending central series of a group $G$ be $$G=\Gamma^1\geq\Gamma^2\geq\cdots$$ where $\Gamma^{q+1}=[G,\Gamma^q]$ for which $\Gamma^q/\Gamma^{q+1}$ is an Abelian group.

Suppose that $G$ is finitely generated, nilpotent and torsion-free and each $\Gamma^q/\Gamma^{q+1}$ is a finitely generated free Abelian group. The paper I am reading claims that it follows that $G$ is finitely presented. May I know why is it so? Given that we know an infinite presentation of $G$ and suppose that a basis for each $\Gamma^q/\Gamma^{q+1}$ is given, how can one fine a specific finite presentation of $G$?

Comment: Hmm, so you have a finite filtration of $G$ by normal subgroups, such that each subfactor is finitely presented. Is this not enough to conclude that $G$ is finitely presented?

Comment: You say that you can find an infinite presentation of $G$. How did you find this? Also, why is it infinite? The fact that your group $G$ is nilpotent should help you out here.

Comment: In general, if $N$ and $G/N$ have finite presentations then so does $G$. There is no need to consider an infinite presentation of $G$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I suppose that it is hopeless to find an explicit presentation of $G$ from presentations of $N$ and $G/N$ as the structure of $G$ is not uniquely determined by $N$ and $G/N$, right? So in my question, we can only prove that $G$ is finitely presented, but cannot find an explicit presentation of $G$?

Comment: Yes, in general, if for example I tell you the ranks of $G/\Gamma_1$ and of $\Gamma_1/\Gamma_2$ as free abelian groups, then $G/\Gamma_2$ is not uniquely determined, but it might be for small ranks.

Comment: Every finitely generated nilpotent group is finitely presented. The same holds for polycyclic groups.