# If $G/N$ and $N$ are finitely presented, then $G$ is finitely presented.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

> Let $G$ be a group and $N\triangleleft G$. Show that if $G/N$ and $N$ are finitely presented, then $G$ is finitely presented.

Worked on this problem for about 2 hours before we all threw in the towel. This is our first attempt, which seems the most valiant

> Let $N=\langle x_1,\dots x_k~|~R\rangle$, and $G/N=\langle y_1N,\dots,y_lN~|~R'\rangle$, where $|R|,|R'|<\infty$.
>
> Now, $G=\langle x_1,\dots,x_k,y_1,\dots,y_l\rangle$. Let $r'\in R'$.
>
> $r'=(y_{i_1}N)^{m_1}(y_{i_2}N)^{m_2}\dots(y_{i_t}N)^{m_t}$
>
> This is equal to $N$ in $G/N$, so $y_{i_1}^{m_1}\dots y_{i_t}^{m_t}x_{j_1}^{n_1}\dots x_{j_s}^{n_s}=1$ (since the $x_i$s generate $N$). This is not unique, but we can pick one such and call it $r''$. Then, we let $R''=\cup r''$, and claim that $G=\langle x_1,\dots x_k,y_1,\dots,y_l~|~R\cup R''\rangle$
>
> Now suppose $H$ is a group, $h\colon\{x_1,\dots,x_k,y_1,\dots,y_l\}\rightarrow H$ a map, and $h(x_i),h(y_j)$ satisfy all relations in $R\cup R''$.
>
> The universal property for $N$ says that there is a unique homomorphism $\phi_1\colon N\rightarrow H$ such that $\phi_1(x_i)=h(x_i)$ for all $i$.
>
> Define $\bar{h}\colon\{y_1N,\dots,y_l N\}\rightarrow H$ by $\bar{h}(y_iN)=h(y_i)$. Now, if $r'\in R'$, we have $h(y_{i_1})^{m_1}\dots h(y_{i_t})^{m_t}h(x_{j_1})^{n_1}h(x_{j_s})^{n_s}=1$ in $H$

I'm not sure what I have here is useful. Suggestions welcome.

I don't believe a proof as constructive as the one I have outlined could possibly work. Clearly, knowing the presentations for $N$ and $G/N$ is not enough to present $G$; $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3$ can build $\mathbb{Z}_6$ or $S_3$, so this approach may be significantly off the mark.

Comment: I think you have used more information than just the presentations of G/N and N, though, when you pick the 'j's and 'n's to form r''.

Comment: You do not have enough relations there to define a presentation of $G$. You also need relations of the form $y_i^{-1}x_jy_i = w_{i,j}$ (one for each  $i$ and $j$), where $w_{i,j}$ is a word in the $x_k$.

Comment: Right, that's a much better formulation of the problem I mention with the $S_3$ or $\mathbb{Z}_6$ case. There should be enough to say that $G$ is finitely presented at least.

Comment: Ah, and @DerekHolt, I see that you claim the result [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495168/finitely-presented-group#comment1064863_495168); do you possibly know a bit more about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is answered by Derek Holt [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813577/). As already mentioned in the comments, you also have to add relations of the form $g n g^{-1} = n'$, where $g$ is a generator of $G$, $n$ is a generator of $N$ and $n'$ is some explicitly described element of $N$.